# Create matrix like HTML table with d3.js

Tags: javascript, matrix, d3.js

i want to create a matrix like table with no numerical values.
1. i have a database table:

```
| CODE |  STIL |  SUBSTIL |  PRODUS |
|------|-------|----------|---------|
|  R   | stil1 | substil1 | produs1 |
|  R   | stil1 | substil2 | produs2 |
|  T   | stil1 | substil3 | produs3 |
|  T+  | stil2 | substil4 | produs4 |
|  G   | stil2 | substil4 | produs5 |
|  R   | stil3 | substil5 | produs6 |
|  R   | stil4 | substil6 | produs7 |
```

1. from this table i can get a jsonfile:

   `var data = [
        {"code": "R","stil": "stil1","substil": "substil1","produs": "produs1"}, 
        {"code": "R","stil": "stil1","substil": "substil2","produs": "produs2"}, 
        {"code": "T","stil": "stil1","substil": "substil3","produs": "produs3"}, 
        {"code": "T+","stil": "stil2","substil": "substil4","produs": "produs4"},
        {"code": "G","stil": "stil2","substil": "substil4","produs": "produs5"},
        {"code": "R","stil": "stil3","substil": "substil5","produs": "produs6"},
        {"code": "R","stil": "stil4","substil": "substil6","produs": "produs7"}
       ];`

I want as final result a table like this:

```
| CODE |            stil1            |  stil2   |   stil3  |   stil4  |
|      | substil1 | substil2 | substil3  | substil4 | substil5 | substil6 |
|------|----------|----------|-----------|----------|----------|----------|
|  R   | produs1  |          |           |          |          |          |
|  R   |          | produs2  |           |          |          |          |
|  R   |          |          |           | produs6  |          |          |
|  R   |          |          |           |          |          | produs7  |
|  T   |          |          |  produs3  |          |          |          |
|  T+  |          |          |           | produs4  |          |          |
|  G   |          |          |           | produs5  |          |          |
```

I tried using this

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/844752

[recursively (or iteratively) make a nested html table with d3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337402/recursively-or-iteratively-make-a-nested-html-table-with-d3-js)

Thank you for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

see [Creating a table linked to a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268645/creating-a-table-linked-to-a-csv-file), but work from the jsfiddle provided since the data structure is very similar... http://jsfiddle.net/7WQjr/

if your data is coming directly from a request, you can:

```
d3.json(url, function(data) {
    code from the jsfiddle making the table goes here
})
```

Comment: thanks, but is just a simple table. i want to transform in matrix or pivot like, but without calculated value (no count,no sum, just plain text);